# How to configure a tun interface on Linux for SSH port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, tunneling, tun

I am trying to forward port 139 from a Windows machine to my Ubuntu SSH server on a tun interface with the ip address 10.0.0.1.

This is so that I can access the windows shares on the machine on my Ubuntu server, through the reverse tunnel.

I can forward ports to 127.0.0.1, but not to 10.0.0.1.

On windows I am using the Tunnelier ssh client.

On my Ubuntu server, the following message is printed in auth.log:

```
Received disconnect from 124.109.51.154: 11: Server denied request for client-side server-2-client forwarding on 10.0.0.1:139.
```

So far i have tried the following settings:

```
GatewayPorts yes
PermitTunnel yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, but it did not work.

I set up the tun like this:

```
sudo tunctl -t loc_0 -u myusername
sudo ifconfig loc_0 inet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

The settings in the Tunneler ssh client should not matter because I can forward port 139 successfully to the Microsoft Loopback Adapter on a Windows machine running the WinSSHD server.

Versions:
  Windows is XP SP3, 
  Ubuntu is 10.10.

---

**Update:**

I tried to forward the port to a number **greater than 1024** mentioning the IP address of the tun, and it successfully connected **but** the forwarding was done on 127.0.0.1 instead of the tun's IP address 10.0.0.1.

So there are two separate problems now, when connecting from the Windows machine:

1) Forwarding on ports less than 1024 is probably being denied. How can we allow that on the server?

2) Forwarding is done only on 127.0.0.1 even if I mention 10.0.0.1 which is the tun's IP address.

*Another attempt:*
I also tried to forward port 22 of a Linux machine to the **tun's port** 55567. It showed success.
But when I tried to ssh into that port using both local addresses, on the Linux machine in its debug display I got the error `Connection failed: no route to host` when using 127.0.0.1 to connect and simply `Connection refused` when using the tun's IP address.

So the tun is not getting the forwarded port no matter we connect from a Windows client or a Linux client.

Comment: Which version of Windows you have? They made bad changes after XP if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Eduardo: I've mentioned the versions of the OS's. Do you have any idea about configuring a tun device for such a purpose, because I can forward the port successfully onto an ssh server running on Windows.

Comment: SSH tunnels and tun interfaces have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Chris S: I want to forward the port to the tun's IP address, instead of 127.0.0.1. How can I do that? Or is it just not possible on Linux?

Comment: I understand now. My apologies. Try `AllowTcpForwarding yes`

Comment: @Chris S: Thanks. I tried the option, but I found that the port 139 and any port less than 1024 I tried was resulting in the error. Though the **tun** is still not getting any port forwarded, even though the server doesn't complain for higher ports on connection.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding <1024 you can only do that by using root for the ssh tunnel:

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-ssh-beyondshell-tcpip.html

> Note
>
> Setting up port forwarding to listen on ports below 1024 requires
>   root level access.

Regarding 127.0.0.1 you probably need to use '-g' in your ssh setup:

> ```
>  -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What´s about this:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 10.0.0.1 up
sudo ssh -g -L 139:10.0.0.1:139 user@sambahost
```